# Ошибки в приложении на Qt

Tags: qt

Только начинаю изучать Qt по учебнику Шлее М. - Профессиональное программирование на C++. +CD. Qt 4.8.,
у меня установлена версия Qt 5.2.1
Создаю проект Qt Quick, в файле main.cpp пишу такой код

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QLabel lbl ("Hello, World!");
    lbl.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

При компиляции вылезает куча ошибок
[image]

Если заменить
`QApplication app(argc, argv);`
на
`QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);`
то ошибок становится меньше
[image]

Как я понимаю, проблема в том, что в qt 5.2.1 подключаемые классы отличаются именами от qt 4.8.
Подскажите, что еще нужно подключить, чтобы приложение заработало?
И  какой тип приложения лучше создавать, чтобы разбирать примеры из учебника Шлее? Qt Quick, Qt Widget или какое-то другое?

Comment: может вам стоит начать с "GUI приложение Qt" вместо "Qt Quick"?

Comment: Как вариант поискать новую версию книги Шлее. Там всё описано под новую версию Qt.

Answer (score 4):

Известная беда =)

Нужно убедиться, что в pro-файле подключен модуль QtWidgets:

```
QT += widgets
```

Так же (на будущее) полезно включать C++11:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

Ну и в исходном коде:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
```

Все-таки в книге версия Qt4.8, а фреймворк развивается достаточно активно в последнее время...
Особое внимание уделите многопоточности (в книге уже не актуальная информация о наследовании от QThread) и новому синтаксису соединения сигналов/слотов, позволяющему использовать лямбда-функции. Да и вообще, советую свои эксперименты проводить в обнимку не только с книгой, но и официальной документацией =)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно создать проект qt widgets. Потом заинклудить QLabel

Answer (score 0):

1. Вам нужно в проекте (.pro) прописать.

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

1. QtGui/QGuiApplication - это старая запись для QT4, в QT5 нужно объявлять отдельно:
   QtGui и QGuiApplication